# Google Play Screenshot Size Resolution

Tags: android, google-play, screenshot

I need to resize my screenshots for Google Play Store Listing for Phone, 7" and 10" tablets, but cannot find an actual resolution. 
Apple App Store gives specific resolutions for screenshots, Google Play does not state what the ratio or resolution of a 7" or 10" tablet.

I'm aware of the minimum-maximum resolutions, but looking for **a generally accepted resolution for Phone & Tablet screenshot submissions.** I doubt 320 x 480 is acceptable for today's 1080p/4K standard screens.

Comment: You simply use the emulator and create a "Phone" and "Tablet", then use the screenshot button. Google Play Store is very flexible. The pixel size is not that important, but the aspect ratio is (I think).

Comment: I'm not using the emulator, I need a specific resolution to use in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any tablet screenshot that fits these guidelines:

> JPEG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha)
> Minimum dimension: 320px
> Maximum dimension: 3840px
> The maximum dimension of your screenshot can't be more than twice as long as the minimum dimension.

More information here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9866151?hl=en-GB&visit_id=637415646559032144-3974075474&rd=1

Answer (score -1):

I would probably just use Google's own [Pixel C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_C) (2,560 x 1,800) and [Nexus 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_(2013)) (1920 x 1200) as references.

If that doesn't do it for you, just google around for some of the latest Android tablets in each category and see what their specs are.

Answer (score -1):

you can use any screen resolution you like, however, i would suggest using these resolutions since they are the [most used](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/most-used-smartphone-screen-resolutions-in-2017) in 2017

**720x1280 is the most used smartphone screen resolution**

in case you wanted to use the latest screen resolution you can use these new arrivals screen resolutions

- Samsung Galaxy Note 8: 1440 x 2960 pixels
- Samsung Galaxy S8: 1440 x 2960 pixels
- LG V30: 1440 x 2880 pixels
- LG G6: 1440 x 2880 pixels
- Sony Xperia XZ Premium: 3840 x 2160 pixels
- iPhone X: 1125 x 2436 pixels (announced)

Comment: You cannot use any screen resolution. Aspect ration must be 1:2. Play Store won't accept 1440 x 2960 pixels. 
These two are fine.
LG V30: 1440 x 2880 pixels
LG G6: 1440 x 2880 pixels